# How can a Page view be 0 for Page depth = 0

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I created an advanced segment with condition  Page depth = 0 and then I found a report under Audience Overview that Page view is 0 for a huge number of session and Users. How is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Users may have zero pageviews when the pageview call failed (or pageview tracking wasn't called in the first place) but other interaction tracking like events (with the non-interaction flag set to a value other than true), user timings, transactions etc. still were fired.